# Using an external css in Flex 4

Tags: adobe, flex4

I'm using the Flex 4 beta and the ability to load an external css seems to be broken.  Running the code below shows no styling at all.  Have I missed something?

Here's the code:

package components
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.StyleSheet;

```
import mx.controls.Label;
import spark.components.Panel;

public class MainPanel extends Panel
{
    private var mainLabel:Label = new Label();
    private var label2:Label = new Label();


    public function MainPanel()
    {
        super();

        var cssUrl:URLRequest = new URLRequest("css/style.css");
        var cssLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        cssLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, cssLoaded);
        cssLoader.load(cssUrl);
    }

    function cssLoaded(event:Event):void {
        var css:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
        css.parseCSS(URLLoader(event.target).data);

        mainLabel.styleSheet = css;
        mainLabel.htmlText = "Main Label";
        mainLabel.horizontalCenter = 0;
        mainLabel.verticalCenter = -350;
        mainLabel.setStyle("styleName", "h1");
        addElement(mainLabel);

        label2.htmlText="Sub-Label";
        label2.horizontalCenter="0";
        label2.verticalCenter="-300";
        addElement(label2);
    }
}
```

}

css/style.css

.h1 {
    color:#ffe145;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 36;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}

Loaded with this code (the s:Application tags get dropped by the stackoverflow software):

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<custom:MainPanel horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CSS file is in a relative position to the SWF on the web server, you can try adding this tag to your application MXML.

```
<fx:Style source="css/style.css"/>
```

That will pull in all the CSS settings and automatically make the assignments for you.